# Prove $xy\leq \frac{x^p}{p} + \frac{y^q}{q}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, theorem-provers

Let $p,q>1,\ \frac1p+\frac1q=1$, and $x,y>0$.

Prove that $xy\leq \frac{x^p}{p} + \frac{y^q}{q}$
by using natural log, definition of concave function, and the fact that natural log is a concave function

Concave function:
$f(tx+(1-t)y)\geq tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$
for every $x,y$ in its domain and $0\leq t \leq 1$

Comment: Unless you explain, and quite a bit, what you wrote makes no sense at all.

Comment: yeah, just edited, first time posting, so didn't get the formatting right the first time

Comment: make sure to take a look at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to learn how to properly post math here

Comment: Got it, thanks for the help

Comment: Your first „sentence“ is missing information. Do you want to prove that if $xy \leq \dots$ then $x,y >0$ or if $x,y>0$ then $xy \leq \dots$.  Also, what are $p$ and $q$? Natural numbers, reals,...?

Comment: That is [Young's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality_for_products) and the Wikipedia page contains a proof.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more, still don't really understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you really want to do is to prove the inequality for $x,y>0$ not that the inequality implies $x,y>0$ since it, for example, also holds for $x=y=-2,\ p=q=2$.

So how do we prove this inequality given the convexity of $\ln$ and $x,y>0$? By using convexity, logarithm laws and our previously stated conditions we get

$$\ln\Big( \frac1p x^p + \frac1q y^q \Big) = \ln\Big( \frac1p x^p + \big(1-\frac1p \big) y^q \Big)$$
$$\geq \frac1p \ln(x^p) + \big( 1-\frac1p\big) \ln(y^q) = \frac1p \ln(x^p) + \frac1q \ln(y^q) = \ln(x) + \ln(y)$$

Appliying $\exp$ on both sides gives you:

$$\frac1p x^p + \frac1q y^q \geq xy$$